# Where the Virtual DOM stores in SSR - React JS

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

all I know the React Virtual DOM stores in the browser memory on the client-side. but in case it's Server-Side Rendering (SSR) where does it store the Virtual DOM. still at client side or server side.?